# Visual Studio Unittest Adapter: how to detect active configuration in executor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I know I can get the current active configuration (`Debug|Release|...`) using the dte object:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;    

public static string GetCurrentActiveConfiguration()
{    
  var dte = (DTE2) ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof (DTE));
  var p = dte?.Solution.SolutionBuild;
  var sc = p?.ActiveConfiguration;
  return sc.Name;
}
```

This works well within the test discovery step of my unit test adapter.

However the TestExecutor (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.ITestExecutor`) is run as a separate process `vstest.executionengine.x86.exe` and thus I seem not to be able to access any information about the visual studio instance.

How can I determine the current active configuration from within the `RunTests` methods? The signature of `RunTests` is:

```
public void RunTests(IEnumerable<string> sources, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
public void RunTests(IEnumerable<TestCase> tests, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I'm not the only one who needed information like this:

Some adaptions need to be made depending on the visual studio version which is used but the mechanism can be understood quite clearly.

```
using EnvDTE;
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ImplemenationCTestTestAdapter
{
    /// <remarks>
    ///  Taken from here: https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-visualstudio/blob/master/Gauge.VisualStudio/Helpers/DTEHelper.cs
    ///         and here: https://github.com/smkanadl/CTestTestAdapter/blob/master/ImplemenationCTestTestAdapter/DTEHelper.cs
    /// </remarks>
    internal static class DteHelper
    {
        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        private static extern int CreateBindCtx(uint reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);

        private static readonly Regex DteRegex = new Regex(@"!\S+\.DTE\.[\d\.]+:\d+");

        internal static DTE GetCurrent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null)
        {
            if (serviceProvider != null)
            {
                return (DTE) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (DTE));
            }
            var currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            var vsProcessId = GetVisualStudioProcessId(currentProcess.Id);
            object runningObject = null;
            IBindCtx bindCtx = null;
            IRunningObjectTable rot = null;
            IEnumMoniker enumMonikers = null;
            try
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx));
                bindCtx.GetRunningObjectTable(out rot);
                rot.EnumRunning(out enumMonikers);
                var moniker = new IMoniker[1];
                var numberFetched = IntPtr.Zero;
                while (enumMonikers.Next(1, moniker, numberFetched) == 0)
                {
                    var runningObjectMoniker = moniker[0];
                    string name = null;
                    try
                    {
                        runningObjectMoniker?.GetDisplayName(bindCtx, null, out name);
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {
                        // do nothing.
                    }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || !DteRegex.IsMatch(name))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (!name.EndsWith(vsProcessId.ToString()))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    rot.GetObject(runningObjectMoniker, out runningObject);
                    break;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (enumMonikers != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(enumMonikers);
                }
                if (rot != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rot);
                }
                if (bindCtx != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(bindCtx);
                }
            }
            return (DTE) runningObject;
        }

        private static int GetVisualStudioProcessId(int testRunnerProcessId)
        {
            var mos =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher($"Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID={testRunnerProcessId}");
            var processes =
                mos.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(mo => Convert.ToInt32(mo["ParentProcessID"])).ToList();
            if (processes.Any())
            {
                return processes.First();
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Class `ManagementObjectSearcher` is contained in assembly `System.Management`. You'll need to add the corresponding reference.

Comment: The answer would be better inlineing the code instead of linking it.

Comment: absolutely right, I added my modified code instead of the original linked one.

Comment: You probably don't need to go so deep, just to mule values. You can use custom 'TestCaseProperty'. Example [here](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-visualstudio/blob/master/Gauge.VisualStudio.TestAdapter/TestDiscoverer.cs#L97).